# SQL statement for Google Sheets QUERY function

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to use Query to comb out Make and Model from a block of text on "Sheet2" by referencing from a larger "Sheet1". Also at the same time  finding out the average price purchased and also how many was purchased in the past.

On sheet1; the reference database of all goods purchased. With Col1 = Brand, Col2 = Model  etc etc...Col5 = Purchase Price. Here items with the same Make and Model could be purchased at various times at different prices.
i.e

Col1 Col2  ... Col5

Apple iPad3  ... $600

Apple iPad3  ... $500

Apple iPad3  ... $400

Sheet2, is the content of a catalogue from a supplier, with Col1 being the description of the products available.

An example of a cell (A5) could read...

"New Apple iPad3 with slightly damaged box"

B5 would return the found Make search "Apple".

C5 would return the found Model search "iPad3"

D5 would return the average price found in search array "$500"

E5 would return the the qty that was found "3"

The trouble I'm experience now is that I cannot get all the above (both Make Model and Avg Price and Count) to co-exist in a single query pass.

This Query is inserted into B5, it's results fills B5, C5, D5...

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:F,"select A,B,F where A<>'' and B<>'' and '"&B5&"' contains A and 
'"&B5&"' contains B limit 1 Label A'', B'', F''")
```

...will return Make Model Price (the first found instance only). What we need is the above with average and count.

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:F,"select avg(F),count(F) where A<>'' and B<>'' and '"&A5&"' contains A 
and '"&A5&"' contains B label avg(F)'',count(F)''")
```

The above works, at retrieving the average and count. 
But as soon as I try to get make and model as well, it fails...

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:F,"select A,B,avg(F),count(F) where A<>'' and B<>'' and 
'"&A5&"' contains A and '"&A5&"' contains B label A'',B'', avg(F)'',count(F)''")
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [group](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Group_By) your output by the dimensions you are aggregating on.

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:F,
"select A,B,avg(F),
count(F) where A<>'' and B<>'' and '"&A5&"' contains A and '"&A5&"' contains B
group by A,B label A'',B'', avg(F)'',count(F)''"
)
```